# After install next to Windows 8, no grub, Windows 8 still booting

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I have a PC running Windows 8.1 on a first SSD.

I bought a second SSD and installed Ubuntu 13.10 on it. The installation completed, even though at some point it stated that no other OS were previously installed -- not sure if that's a problem. I specified the first disk (the one with Windows) as the disk to place the boot sector.

After installation, there was no grub menu, and Windows starts.

I used a grub recovery disk which I used in the past to reinstall grub after a Windows reinstall. It completed successfully (recognizing Windows this time) putting boot sector on both disks.

However, the behavior didn't change: no grub menu, and Windows starts.

Repair info follows in case it might help.

```
                 Boot Info Script 0.60-git      [2 Jan 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.04 2011-04-18
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 1849120 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. SYSLINUX is installed in the  directory. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux/syslinux.cfg /ldlinux.sys

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 13.10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       718,847       716,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             718,848   488,394,751   487,675,904   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32017047552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 62533296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *             32    62,530,623    62,530,592   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdc: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1                   1   234,441,647   234,441,647  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdc1           2,048   234,440,703   234,438,656 Data partition (Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        78A05CE4A05CAA80                       ntfs       Réservé au système
/dev/sda2        1C0A5DD60A5DAD90                       ntfs       
/dev/sdb1        C079-9C1A                              vfat       MYLINUXLIVE
/dev/sdc1        adc402a7-f70c-4ef7-94ec-d36c1846103a   ext4       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sdb1        /media/MYLINUXLIVE       vfat       (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush)
/dev/sr0         /live/image              iso9660    (ro,noatime)


=========================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

[ edited ]

========================= sdb1/syslinux/syslinux.cfg: ==========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# D-I config version 2.0
include menu.cfg
default vesamenu.c32
prompt 0
timeout 50
ui gfxboot bootlogo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================= sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux: ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1
            ?? = ??             syslinux/chain.c32                             1
            ?? = ??             syslinux/gfxboot.c32                           1
            ?? = ??             syslinux/syslinux.cfg                          1
            ?? = ??             syslinux/vesamenu.c32                          1

============== sdb1: Version of COM32(R) files used by Syslinux: ===============

 syslinux/chain.c32                 :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
 syslinux/gfxboot.c32               :  COM32R module (v4.xx)
 syslinux/vesamenu.c32              :  COM32R module (v4.xx)

=========================== sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

[edited]

=============================== sdc1/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=adc402a7-f70c-4ef7-94ec-d36c1846103a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdc1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
            ?? = ??             boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic              2
            ?? = ??             boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic              1
            ?? = ??             boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic                 1
            ?? = ??             boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic                 1
            ?? = ??             boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic.efi.signed      1
            ?? = ??             initrd.img                                     2
            ?? = ??             vmlinuz                                        1

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

File descriptor 7 (pipe:[5552]) leaked on lvscan invocation. Parent PID 8592: bash
File descriptor 8 (pipe:[5552]) leaked on lvscan invocation. Parent PID 8592: bash
  No volume groups found
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
**************** log of boot-repair 2014-01-28__21h42 ****************
boot-repair version : 3.16-0ppa2~lucid
boot-sav version : 3.17-0ppa4~lucid
g2s version : 0.3.01.1-0ppa1~lucid
internet: no-internet
internet: no-internet
File descriptor 7 (pipe:[5552]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 3223: /bin/sh
File descriptor 8 (pipe:[5552]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 3223: /bin/sh
No volume groups found
LIVESESSION is : yes (Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.3 (squeeze) , squeeze , Debian , x86_64  )
BYTES_BEFORE_PART[1] (sda) = 2048 sectors * 512 bytes = 1048576 bytes.
BYTES_BEFORE_PART[2] (sdc) = 2048 sectors * 512 bytes = 1048576 bytes.
BYTES_BEFORE_PART[3] (sdb) = 32 sectors * 512 bytes = 16384 bytes.

OSPROBER:
/dev/sda1:Windows Recovery Environment (loader):Windows:chain
/dev/sdc1:Ubuntu 13.10 (13.10):Ubuntu:linux

BLKID:
/dev/sda1: LABEL="RM-CM-)servM-CM-) au systM-CM-(me" UUID="78A05CE4A05CAA80" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sda2: UUID="1C0A5DD60A5DAD90" TYPE="ntfs"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="adc402a7-f70c-4ef7-94ec-d36c1846103a" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="MYLINUXLIVE" UUID="C079-9C1A" TYPE="vfat"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"

2 disks with OS, 2 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 1 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.
Total of 1 OS detected on sda disk.
Total of 1 OS detected on sdc disk.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

LIST_GPTPART[1] is 3 (sdc1 , sdc)
TABLE_TYPE of sda is MSDos
ReadEFI: /dev/sdc , N 128 , 0 ,  , PRStart 1024 , PRSize 128
part /dev/sdc1 is notBISEFI
TABLE_TYPE of sdc is EFI
TABLE_TYPE of sdb is MSDos
sda1 : sda, not-sepboot, no-grub-install, grub , no-update-grub, no-apt-nor-yum, 32, no boot, /mnt/boot-sav/sda1, with-os, no-gpt, notEFItable, no-fstab.
sda2 : sda, is-maybe-sepboot, no-grub-install, grub , no-update-grub, no-apt-nor-yum, 32, no boot, /mnt/boot-sav/sda2, no-os, no-gpt, notEFItable, no-fstab.
sdc1 : sdc, not-sepboot, grub-install, grub2 , update-grub, apt-get, 64, with boot, /mnt/boot-sav/sdc1, with-os, gpt, notBISEFI, fstab-without-efi.
sdb1 : sdb, is-maybe-sepboot, no-grub-install, grub , no-update-grub, no-apt-nor-yum, 32, with boot, /media/MYLINUXLIVE, no-os, no-gpt, notEFItable, no-fstab.

PARTED:

Model: ATA Samsung SSD 840 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
1      1049kB  368MB  367MB  primary  ntfs         boot
2      368MB   250GB  250GB  primary  ntfs


Model: SanDisk Extreme (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1      16.4kB  32.0GB  32.0GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


Model: ATA SanDisk SDSSDXP1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 120GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
1      1049kB  120GB  120GB  ext4




Warning: Unable to open /dev/sr0 read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sr0
has been opened read-only.


Error: /dev/sr0: unrecognised disk label


MOUNT:
aufs on / type aufs (rw)
tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sr0 on /live/image type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
tmpfs on /live/cow type tmpfs (rw,noatime,mode=755)
tmpfs on /live type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/MYLINUXLIVE type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush)
/dev/sda1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda1 type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /mnt/boot-sav/sda2 type fuseblk (rw,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdc1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sdc1 type ext4 (rw)


/sys/block/sda:  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sda1 sda2 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sdb:  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sdb1 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sdc:  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro sdc1 size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/sys/block/sr0:  alignment_offset bdi capability dev device ext_range holders inflight power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent
/dev:  block bsg btrfs-control bus cdrom cdrw char console core cpu_dma_latency disk dvd dvdrw fd full fuse hidraw0 hidraw1 hidraw2 hidraw3 hidraw4 hpet initctl input kmsg log MAKEDEV mcelog md mem net network_latency network_throughput null port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rtc rtc0 scd0 sda sda1 sda2 sdb sdb1 sdc sdc1 sg0 sg1 sg2 sg3 shm snapshot snd sndstat sr0 stderr stdin stdout urandom usb v4l vga_arbiter video0 xconsole zero

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


DF:

Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
aufs          aufs    3.8G  9.3M  3.8G   1% /
tmpfs        tmpfs    3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /lib/init/rw
udev         tmpfs    3.8G  184K  3.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs        tmpfs    3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sr0   iso9660    339M  339M     0 100% /live/image
tmpfs        tmpfs    3.8G  9.3M  3.8G   1% /live/cow
tmpfs        tmpfs    3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /live
tmpfs        tmpfs    3.8G  8.0K  3.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/sdb1     vfat     30G  888M   29G   3% /media/MYLINUXLIVE
/dev/sda1  fuseblk    350M  259M   92M  74% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2  fuseblk    233G  104G  129G  45% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdc1     ext4    111G  3.8G  101G   4% /mnt/boot-sav/sdc1

FDISK:

Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00007c51

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2          718848   488394751   243837952    7  HPFS/NTFS

Disk /dev/sdc: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1   234441647   117220823+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32017047552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 62533296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000c1e14

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          32    62530623    31265296    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)



************************Before mainwindow
FSCK_ACTION no PASTEBIN_ACTION yes
recommendedrepair, reinstall, REINSTALL_POSSIBLE yes PURGE_POSSIBLE yes
UNHIDEBOOT_ACTION yes (10s), noflag (sda1)
PART_TO_REINSTALL_GRUB sdc1, PART_TO_REINSTALL_GRUB_PURGE sdc1, FORCE_GRUB all (sdc) REMOVABLEDISK no
USE_SEPARATEBOOTPART no (sda2) grub2 (sda1)
UNCOMMENT_GFXMODE no ATA  ADD_KERNEL_OPTION no (acpi=off)
MBR_TO_RESTORE sda (mbr) ( )
Warning: unknown mime-type for "/mnt/boot-sav/sdc1/etc/default/grub" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no "view" mailcap rules found for type "application/octet-stream"
adding: log/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/log/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdc1/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdc/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdc/current_mbr.img (deflated 100%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdb1/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdb/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdb/current_mbr.img (deflated 97%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sda2/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sda1/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sda/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sda/current_mbr.img (deflated 95%)
adding: log/log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/2014-01-28__21h42.boot-repair.log.tee (deflated 75%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdb1/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdb/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdb/current_mbr.img (deflated 97%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdc1/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdc/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sdc/current_mbr.img (deflated 100%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sda2/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sda1/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sda/ (stored 0%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/sda/current_mbr.img (deflated 95%)
adding: log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/2014-01-28__21h42.boot-repair.log.tee
zip warning:  file size changed while zipping log/2014-01-28__21h42boot-repair33/2014-01-28__21h42.boot-repair.log.tee
(deflated 82%)
internet: no-internet

************************Actions
FSCK_ACTION no PASTEBIN_ACTION yes
recommendedrepair, reinstall, REINSTALL_POSSIBLE yes PURGE_POSSIBLE yes
UNHIDEBOOT_ACTION yes (10s), noflag (sda1)
PART_TO_REINSTALL_GRUB sdc1, PART_TO_REINSTALL_GRUB_PURGE sdc1, FORCE_GRUB all (sdc) REMOVABLEDISK no
USE_SEPARATEBOOTPART no (sda2) grub2 (sda1)
UNCOMMENT_GFXMODE no ATA  ADD_KERNEL_OPTION no (acpi=off)
MBR_TO_RESTORE sda (mbr) (sda 1)
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdc1/etc/default/grub
Reinstall the GRUB of sdc1 into all MBRs of disks with OS or not-USB
Reinstall the GRUB of sdc1 into the MBR of sda
dpkg --configure -a sdc1
grub-install (GRUB) 2.00-19ubuntu2.1
chroot: failed to run command `type': No such file or directory
INSTALLOUTPUT: source_dir doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory
INSTALLEXIT:1
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Reinstall the GRUB of sdc1 into the MBR of sdc
dpkg --configure -a sdc1
grub-install (GRUB) 2.00-19ubuntu2.1
chroot: failed to run command `type': No such file or directory
INSTALLOUTPUT: source_dir doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory
INSTALLEXIT:1
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-15-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-15-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 8 (loader) on /dev/sda1
Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdc1/boot/grub/grub.cfg
internet: no-internet
internet: no-internet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by reinstalling everything making sure I have a separate partition for grub boot (as suggested by a newer boot repair), and since that still didn't work, running boot repair again on this new fresh install.